# Running Service workers continuosly in background?

Tags: service-worker

I have been learning about Service workers today only. I have a couple of questions

1) what are the limiation of using service workers other than the https? I read that the lifetime of the service worker is limited, is it possible for me to keep the service worker running in the background as long as the browser (not my page) is opened? if possible, what could be the issue?

2) When a event is running using service workers, by mistake i close the tab, when i open my page, is it possible for me to check what are the pending events that are running in my service worker? If possible could you give me a short example?

3) Is there a limitation on how many pages to be cached? What can be cached and what shouldn't?

Thanks,

Jollyguy

Answer (score 8):

1. Currently there's no way to keep a service worker running indefinitely while your tab is closed. The [BackgroundSync API](https://github.com/WICG/BackgroundSync/blob/master/explainer.md) might be what you're looking for.
2. It is definitely possible, you can make your page "chat" with its controlling service worker using the [postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Client/postMessage). See the [Message Relay recipe in the ServiceWorker Cookbook](https://serviceworke.rs/message-relay.html).
3. There isn't a limitation, other than the amount of available space. See [the Storage Consideration paragraph of the Service Workers specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#storage-considerations) for more details.

Comment: It should be said that you can start it occasionally at will with the Push API, that requires a dynamic server